# Como faço um evento em lua?

Tags: lua, eventos, event-listener

eu quero saber como fazer um evento, por exemplo com o faço pra ver se o usuario digitou 'q' ou 'o', como se fosse em um `addEventListener()`

Comment: Pergunta no SOen: [KeyPress event in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5689566/1452488)

Answer (score -1):

Lua é uma linguagem bem simples, por padrão não possui bibliotecas para tratar eventos muito menos interfaces de usuário. Talvez você esteja usando Lua em um contexto específico, se for o caso, as bibliotecas disponíveis para você usar devem ser documentadas pela ferramenta em si.

Por exemplo: o pacote [ltui](https://github.com/tboox/ltui) apresenta bindings em Lua para usar ncurses (biblioteca para criação de interfaces de usuário no terminal). Nesse caso o loop de eventos é totalmente gerido pelo ncurses e a gente só usa ele dentro da nossa aplicação Lua.

Como citado por @Woss, a pergunta feita [em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5689566/1452488) tem respostas mais aprofundadas.

Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas acho importante para pessoas como eu que estão aprendendo a programar em Lua terem uma resposta mais direta e simples.